# Laravel: How do I make a Redis queued job fail?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel while running Redis queues, I'm unable to get the `failed` method called in my Job class. I want to make sure I can properly log them and that they are written to the failed_jobs table.

Laravel documentation about queues [states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues)

> You may define a failed method directly on your job class, allowing you to perform job specific clean-up when a failure occurs. This is the perfect location to send an alert to your users or revert any actions performed by the job. **The Exception that caused the job to fail will be passed to the failed method**:

I'm not 100% sure what Laravel consider to be "the exception that caused the job to fail". Below is a very simple job class. All that's appearing in my logs is `It did not work` and `exception caught`.

I'm launching this queue with the following command, specifically setting `tries` to 1 so it doesn't attempt to re-run the job.

```
php artisan queue:work redis --queue=widgets --tries=1
```

How can I get the failed method to be called and the job to appear in the failed_jobs table?

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;
use Exception;
use App\Processors\WidgetProcessor;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class WidgetJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct($widget)
    {
        $this->widget = $widget;
    }

    public function handle(WidgetProcessor $processor)
    {
        Redis::throttle('WidgetJob')->allow(5)->every(60)->then(function () use ($processor) {
            try {
                $var = false;
                if($var == false) {
                    Log::notice('It did not work');
                    throw new Exception;
                } else {
                    Log::notice('It worked');
                }
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                Log::notice('Exception caught');
            }          
        }, function () {
            return $this->release(5);
        });
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        Log::notice('failed was called');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're catching the exception, which means the `handle` function return is `void`. Without an exception, the job was successfully executed. Let the exception bubble up so Laravel will tag it as failed.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu not sure what you mean. I can't use try without catch. When I try to remove the throw statement, I just get "It did not work". But the fail method still isn't called. I discovered that if I throw and catch a ReflectionException then fail does get called, but it complains about the type of Exception ... So still not quite there yet.

Comment: Stop using try catch. If you catch the exception, fail will not be triggered because Laravel will think the job was successfully executed. If you really want to use Try Catch, rethrow the exception back in your catch block.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu thanks for this, got it working. Please post an answer so I can accept it and you get some points :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel Queue system works as a daemon that picks up jobs, runs them and moves on. If your job **never** throws exception, Laravel will consider it as a successful job. The problem in your snippet is this:

```
try {
  ... 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    Log::notice('Exception caught');
}
```

By catching the exception, you don't let Laravel mark this job as failed.

You have two choices here: Either don't use `try...catch` or, if you really want to use it, re-throw the exception as follows:

```
try {
  ... 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    Log::notice('Exception caught');

    throw $e;
}
```

By letting the exception bubble up, Laravel will fail the job and invoke your `failed()` routine.